# Reversing order of list using criteria in spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

so i am trying to reverse somehow my list after getting it in my database by using spring hibernate but i don't have much idea about the criteria here is my code by the way

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Crime")
public String show(Map<String, Object> map) 
{
    map.put("complainList", complainService.listComplains());
    return "/complains/Crime";
}
```

my DAO

```
public interface ComplainsDao 
{
   public List<Complains> listComplains();
}
```

my DAO IMPLEMENTATION

```
@Repository
public class ComplainsDaoImpl implements ComplainsDao 
{
   public List<Complains> listComplains() 
   {
      return getSession().createCriteria(Complains.class).list();
   }
}
```

Service

```
public interface ComplainService 
{
    public List<Complains> listComplains();
}
```

Service implementation

```
@Service
public class ComplainsServiceImpl implements ComplainService 
{
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public List<Complains> listComplains() 
   {
      return complainsDao.listComplains();
   }
}
```

Comment: reverse in what sense, any field etc

Comment: those datas have an id which is complainId it shows me an order ascending 1234 it should be in descending order 4321

Comment: are you using annotaions, JPa or Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Criteria` has an `addOrder` method for this:

```
public List<Complains> listComplains() {
    return getSession().createCriteria(Complains.class).addOrder(Order.desc("complainId")).list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `Comparator` or `Comparable` for design of your `Complain` class just change the logic of comparing in `compare` or `compareTo` method

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above answer by @bedrin

You can order the results using `org.hibernate.criterion.Order`.

have a look at below links for some complex examples as well.

[from hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-ordering)

similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780129/order-by-using-criteria-api)

Also you can make use of annotation **OrderBy**

```
@OneToMany
@org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy("childName")
Set<Child> childs
```

or **JPA** `@javax.persistence.OrderBy`